# What does this Terraria flag mean?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I keep running into this flag (the same as the NPC ones). It is red with a blue star on it and I am positive it is not just some banner. I looked it up on google  and the terraria wiki but I have no idea what it is. Anyone know?

[image: red flag with blue star]

Comment: What version of the game are you playing? Mobile? PC? (I'm guessing the former, based on the screenshot).

Comment: I am currently playing the mobile version

Comment: I see [a thread](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/can-anyone-tell-me-what-this-banner-is.39034/) discussing theories, with one person claiming it's an indication as to where the Angler NPC can be found. My best guess is that this is some sort of debugging / development aid that was inadvertently left in the game.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that people have found that this flag is linked to where the Sleeping Angler is.

From [this forum](http://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/can-anyone-tell-me-what-this-banner-is.39034/):

> It's a symbol that shows when the angler is sleeping and if you look you'll see it's right above the angler! But when you wake the angler up it disappears!

I've also found [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=giFCNbIaHa8) that shows this banner above the Angler and how it disappears once you wake him.

It will either be attached to a floating island if one is above the Angler, or it will be hanging in midair from the edge of the top of the map.

Answer (score 3):

This banner spawns on top of the sleeping angler. Jump down and the Angler should be there:)

Answer (score -5):

It is an NPC flag, but for what NPC I can not be certain. Hope this helped a little, I am not there in the game, but it is for sure an NPC flag.